# I can't update IBM DSX Desktop

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

I'm updating to the newest version of IBM DSX Desktop 1.1.7.  The install process stalls and displays

```
"Downloading DSX... 0%".
```

The file desktop.log ends with lines

```
“The size is 83.85 and installsize is 14.73”
```

and

```
“Docker Storage Requirement Failed”.
```

The Docker app is up to date. I’ve tried the usual reboot, etc without success.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on the DSX Desktop team. You might be encountering a bug with the installation code. The good news is that it's a pretty simple fix if you are. Here's how to check:

#### Diagnosis & Fix

- Open up your terminal or command prompt and run `docker system df`. Look for the entry that corresponds to `IMAGE SIZE`. If the unit is in `kB` or `B`, then you're encountering the bug.
- To fix it, run `docker pull busybox`. Once the pull completes, you should be able to update DSX Desktop. After it successfully updates, you can run `docker rmi busybox`.
- If the unit is in `GB`, then that means your existing images are taking up too much space. The limit is `60GB` so make sure your `IMAGE SIZE + installSize <= 60GB`.

#### Explanation

- There's a typo in the code that causes the installer to mistake `kB` and `B` for `GB`. Thus, if you have an `IMAGE SIZE` of `83.85kB`, the installer will treat it as `83.85GB` and will complain about being over the `60GB` limit.
- So to fix it, we pull a temporary image `busybox`, which updates our `IMAGE SIZE` to be in `MB`, allowing us to avoid the bug. After we successfully update DSX Desktop, we can remove the temporary image.

This has been patched and will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `dsx-desktop.log` has the following error:

```
[2017-11-04 19:52:03:0214] [error] exec error: Error: Command failed: eval $(docker-machine env ibm-dsx) && docker system df
docker: 'system' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.

[2017-11-04 19:52:03:0214] [error] stderr: docker: 'system' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
```

It turns out "docker system" command is only available after Docker API version 1.25. Check your API version from the output of "docker version".

After I reinstalled a docker version with API version 1.33, it is able to download.

Comment: I've checked I'm using the last version.  

`[2017-11-06 11:13:31:0696] [info] Docker Version: Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4`

I've executed as Admin too.